# $\lim_{x \to a} x^2 = a^2$.

Tags: calculus, limits

As per the definition of limits if $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)= L$, then $$\forall \varepsilon \gt 0 \ \exists \delta \gt 0 \ s.t 0\lt\lvert x-a \rvert \lt \delta \ \implies \ 0\lt \lvert f(x)- L\rvert \lt \varepsilon $$

I want to prove that $\lim_{x \to a} x^2 = a^2$.
As per the definition $$\lvert f(x)- L\rvert = \lvert x^2- a^2\rvert = \lvert (x-a)(x+a)\rvert =\lvert x-a\rvert \lvert x+a \rvert$$

As per definition $$\lvert x-a \rvert \lt \delta \implies -\delta \lt x-a \lt \delta \implies a-\delta \lt x <a+\delta \implies 2a-\delta \lt x+a <2a+\delta $$

I'm stuck beyond this. I cannot find a suitable $\varepsilon$ to satisfy my condition here.

Comment: take $\delta=\min(|a|,\epsilon)$ you get $|x^2-a^2|<3|a|\epsilon$

Comment: I think the idea put forward by the OP is a good one. Why do the solutions seems to go off the deep end?

Comment: Note that you have $2a-1<x+a<2a+1$ so we have that $|x+a|<2|a|+1$ (since $|x+a|=|(x-a)+2a|\leqslant |x-a|+2|a|$) and then $|x^{2}-a^{2}|=|x-a||x+a|=(2|a|+1)\delta$. Now you can choose $\delta(\varepsilon)=\min\left\{1,\frac{\varepsilon}{2|a|+1}\right\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative approach:

Without loss of generality, $a > 0$.  That is, the approach for $a < 0$ is similar, while the approach if $a = 0$ is trivial.

If $\delta = \epsilon,$ then $|x-a| < \delta \implies |x-a| < \epsilon$.

Instead, take 
$\displaystyle \delta = \min\left(\frac{a}{2},\frac{\epsilon}{3a}\right)$.

Then, $|x - a| < \delta \implies \frac{a}{2} < x < \frac{3a}{2}$.

This implies that $|x + a| < \frac{5a}{2} < 3a$.

So, you have that $|x - a| < \delta$ and 
$|x + a| < 3a$.

Therefore

$|x^2 - a^2| = |x - a| \times |x + a| < \delta \times 3a \leq \epsilon$.

Comment: I like your approach....but why did you take $\delta = \frac{a}{2}$ in the begining?

Comment: @Orpheus, I took $\displaystyle\delta = \min\left(\frac{a}{2}, \frac{\epsilon}{3a}\right)$ so that I could infer that $\displaystyle x < \frac{3a}{2} \implies (x + a) < \frac{5a}{2} < 3a.$

Comment: This is just a question....so I'm allowed to pick any $\delta$?

Comment: $\delta$ has to (somehow) be based on $\epsilon$.  However, additional constraints can be assigned to $\delta$, that are based on fixed values.  For example, with $a$ assumed to be a fixed positive number, you can force $\delta \leq \frac{a}{2}$.  Similarly, in *other* problems, if you want to guarantee that $\delta^2 < \delta$, you can force $\delta \leq 1.$

Comment: So for this problem, I could try a different $\delta$?

Comment: @Orpheus Yes.  In fact, look at the other answers.  These other answers set $\delta$ in a variety of ways.

Comment: Thanks a lot @user2661923

Answer (score 6):

A different approach for the sake of curiosity.

Let $0 < |x - a| < \delta_{\varepsilon}$. Then we have that:
\begin{align*}
|f(x) - L| & = |x^{2} - a^{2}|\\\\
& = |(x-a)(x+a)|\\\\
& = |x - a||(x - a) + 2a|\\\\
& \leq |x - a|(|x - a| + 2|a|)\\\\
& < \delta_{\varepsilon}(\delta_{\varepsilon} + 2|a|) := \varepsilon
\end{align*}

where you can choose the positive root of the corresponding equation on $\delta_{\varepsilon}$.

Comment: you are saying that I frame quadratic roots in terms of a and $\varepsilon$?

Comment: That's the point. Given a certain $\varepsilon > 0$, you can choose

$$\delta_{\varepsilon} = -|a| + \sqrt{a^{2} + \varepsilon}$$

so that the corresponding definition is satisfied.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Átila Correia

Comment: This is definitely the best answer, as this approach is by far the simplest and most intuitive.

Comment: @Orpheus You are welcome ! I am glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

You must find a solution to the equation in $\delta$

$$|x-a|<\delta\implies|x^2-a^2|<\epsilon.$$

The RHS is

$$\sqrt{a^2-\epsilon}<x<\sqrt{a^2+\epsilon}$$ or

$$\sqrt{a^2-\epsilon}-a<x-a<\sqrt{a^2+\epsilon}-a.$$

So if we take

$$0<\delta<\min(a-\sqrt{a^2-\epsilon},\sqrt{a^2+\epsilon}-a)$$ the conditions are fulfilled.

Note that if $\epsilon\ge a^2$, the condition $a^2-x^2<\epsilon$ is automatically fulfilled by $0\le x\le a$.

Comment: thanks a lot, @Pat Bol

Answer (score 1):

For all real numbers $x$ and $a$ we have
\begin{eqnarray}
|x^2-a^2|&=&|(x-a)(x+a)|\cr
&=&|x-a||x+a|\cr
&=&|x-a||(x-a)+a|\cr
&\le&|x-a|(|x-a|+|a|)\cr
&=& |x-a|^2+|a||x-a|
\end{eqnarray}
If $\varepsilon>0$ is such that

$$
|x-a|^2+|a||x-a|<\varepsilon,
$$

then
$$
\frac{-|a|-\sqrt{a^2+4\varepsilon}}{2}<|x-a|<\frac{-|a|+\sqrt{a^2+4\varepsilon}}{2}
$$

Hence, if we choose
$$
\delta=\frac{-|a|+\sqrt{a^2+4\varepsilon}}{2}=\frac{2\varepsilon}{|a|+\sqrt{a^2+4\varepsilon}}>0
$$
for all $x$ satisfying $|x-a|<\delta$, we have $|x^2-a^2|<\varepsilon$

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Mercy King